# After Creating new app its not visible in ItunesConnect MyApp List?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I created new app using itunesconnect. After creating it, its not visible in itunesConnect under **MyApps** but it is present in **users and roles**

[image]

This image i was added from **users and roles**

Even when i **archive** its showing in my app list

Answer (score 1):

The Problem i faced due to i didn't the latest accepted the agreement from the apple side ,so after i accepted my agreement like this

[Eg for accepting agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724066/itunes-connect-agreements-tax-and-banking-message-will-not-go-away)

My app visible under **MyApp** section.

**Steps to follow:**

1.Go to Itunes connect ,read about the agreement accept it.

2.then your app will visible